# In Roblox how can I use :GetTouchingParts() to get all parts a player is currently touching?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a client-side function where when triggered, it teleports the player to any player that is currently touching a spawn location, but I can't get it working.

````lua
player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
character = player.Character

local function tp()
    for _, pplayer in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        for _, part in pairs(pplayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart:GetTouchingParts()) do
            if pplayer == player then continue end
            if part.Name == "SpawnLocation" then
                character:MoveTo(pplayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position + Vector3.new(0, 15, 0))
                break
            end
        end
    end
end

tp()
```
````